# How can I set a custom error page for database fatal error uncaught exception

Tags: maintenance-mode

Every once in a while when I get a fatal PDO error, Drupal outputs the page without the theming and outputs the error message onto the screen. On my production site, it just outputs the page without the error message since I've disabled error reporting in php.ini. Still, I'd like that ugly looking themeless page on my prod site to be themed and informs users an error has occurred and assure them it is reported to the webmaster.

I tried creating a maintenance-page.tpl.php and maintenance-page--offline.tpl.php files and placed them in my general theme folder where all the other templates are, but it doesn't seem to get called. I also set error reporting to "none" in the admin/config/development/logging but it still outputs the error.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: On my production site, it just outputs the page without the error message since I've disabled error reporting in php.ini why do not you allow it to show error logs in php.ini,untill you know what the issue is.

Comment: I know what the issue is from the server logs. The problem is that I want to display a custom message to the users. Sorry if my OP isn't clear. What page does your prod site outputs when fatal error happens? Are you able to show a custom message? If so how - that would solve my problem.